# VS Code dev container: configure workspace to use symbolic link rather than link target

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

At work we use dev containers to provide a consistent development environment to devs.

Since any changes to a running Docker container don't persist over restarts, we mount a directory on the host which contains our source code to a path in the running container.

In order to make user file permissions easier to work with and prevent unintended changes to the running container, we don't use the root user in the container.

Rather we create a user on container startup with the same user id and group id as the host user.

```
docker exec --user root 
        sh -c 'groupadd -g {gid} {group} &&
               useradd -u {uid} -g {group} -s {shell} -d {home} {user} &&
               mkdir -p {home} &&
               chmod 755 {home} &&
               chown {user}:{group} {home}'
```

And we then create a symbolic link into the new user's home directory to the mounted source tree.

```
docker exec --user {user} ln -s /work/src {home}/src
```

When we connect to the container, we just `cd ~/src` and away we go.

However, when using the dev container plugin in VS Code, even if we open a workspace folder at `~/src`, sometimes it will resolve the symbolic link to an absolute path, `/work/src`.

As an example, I can open a file in `~/src`, but then when I'm debugging, if I step into a new file, it will open the file under `/work/src`.

Now I have 2 copies of the same file open, with different paths. Breakpoints are set to different files.

I cannot hard link a directory.

Is there any way to configure VS Code to always use the symlink directory?